# Kubernetes cluster setup config

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing

i have to create a cluster.

i am shooting my questions here…
1). How many worker nodes can handled by t3.medium master node?
2). How pods can be created inside t3.small worker node ?
3). if i create t3.small instance as worker node and pods inside it , how containers can be created in each pod.?
4). can we create master in minikube and create worker node in aws ec2 , can we combine this both and create a cluster?
5). is this any formula to calculate cluster setup and master and worker node?

Tried to calculate but couldn't find apt and exact answer .

Answer (score 0):

Since each Pod is assigned its own IP address, the number of IP addresses supported by an instance type is a factor in determining the number of Pods that can run on the instance.

For this, Amazon EKS provides a script that you can download and run to determine the Amazon EKS recommended maximum number of Pods to run on each instance type.

The script uses hardware attributes of each instance, and configuration options, to determine the maximum Pods number. You can use the number returned in these steps to enable capabilities such as assigning IP addresses to Pods from a different subnet than the instance's and significantly increasing the number of IP addresses for your instance.

1. Download a script that you can use to calculate the maximum number of Pods for each instance type.

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/master/files/max-pods-calculator.sh
```

2. Run the script, replacing `m5.large` with the instance type that you plan to deploy i.e ***t3.small*** and `1.9.0-eksbuild.1` with your Amazon VPC CNI add-on version.

```
./max-pods-calculator.sh --instance-type m5.large --cni-version 1.9.0-eksbuild.1
```

You can find more details in this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-vpc-cni-increases-pods-per-node-limits/)

If you are interested to know what is the recommended instance types based on resource criteria like vcpus and memory, you can use the tool [ec2-instance-selector](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ec2-instance-selector) which recommends instance types based on resource criteria like vcpus and memory and many more.